# Compute the expected number of descents in a random permutations $\in$ $S_n$

Tags: probability

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of [n]. There is a descent at i, $1\leq i\leq n$, if $\sigma(i)>\sigma(i+1)$. Compute the expected number of descents in a random permutations $\in$ $S_n$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you say something about the relation between the expected number of descents and the expected number of ascents? What is the expected number of places where $\sigma$ changes ins _some_ direction?

Comment: Linearity of expectation. Randomly choose a location, then compute the expectation. Then sum them up.

Comment: Sounds good. Which answer does that lead to?

Comment: Alternatively, you can pair up a permutation with another permutation so that the total 'descents' is a constant.

Comment: I get the answer $n/2 *n!$. But I am not sure.

Comment: Linearity of expectation works.  Also works to say that there are $n-1$ places where $\sigma(i) \neq \sigma(i+1)$, and note that by symmetry you should expect equal numbers of ascents and descents.

Comment: @Kimmi: Where do you get the factor of $n!$ from?

Comment: @mjqxxxx $\sigma(i)\neq\sigma(i+1)$, equal numbers of ascents and descents are really a good idea. But how, please give more details.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I made a mistake

Comment: @mjqxxxx so the result will be $(n-1)/2$

Answer (score 1):

There are $n-1$ places for comparison, either descents or ascents, and they are symmetric. So the expected number of descents in permutation is $\frac{n-1}{2}$